# How to slice an input and put it in different lines (python)

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I have an input for different questions so the user should be able to type all the answers within one line and get the output as

```
Q1 c
Q2 b
Q3 d
```

but when I slice my current input I get `c b d` ( i need them on different lines)

Code:

```
input_str = "What are your answers for Q1 to Q10? (leave a space between each answer) " 

qns = input(input_str)

print(qns)

questions = qns.split(" ")

Q1 = (questions[0])

Q2 = (questions[1])

Q3 = (questions[2])

Q4 = (questions[3])
```

Output:

```
What are your answers for Q1 to Q10? (leave a space between each answer) a b c d e

a b c d
```

Comment: Can you provide real input and output for a better understanding?

Comment: input_str = "What are your answers for Q1 to Q10? (leave a space between each answer) "
qns = input(input_str)
print(qns)
questions = qns.split(" \t ")
Q1 = (questions[0])
Q2 = (questions[1])
Q3 = (questions[2])
Q4 = (questions[3])
Q5 = (questions[4])

Comment: What are your answers for Q1 to Q10? (leave a space between each answer) a b c d e
a b c d e  (this is the output)

Comment: I mean without more information the only thing I can suggest is to use "\n" to add a newline manually!

Comment: I think you are splitting by tab character `\t` instead of using the space. Try splitting by space `qns.split(" ")`. Then, questions should be the list of answers. Then, you can use a for loop for iterating over the list and print the answers line by line.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Is the user requested to enter 10 answers? Do you mean to have 'Q1 d' ....  until 'Q10 a' as output? Why do you use these variables `Q1`, `Q2` and so on? Do you plan to use them, or do you do that with the intention of printing your expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your question really is what I imagine, you could do:

```
input_str = "What are your answers for Q1 to Q10? (leave a space between each answer) " 
answers_string = input(input_str)

answers = answers_string.split()
for num, answer in enumerate(answers, start=1):
    print(f'Q{num} {answer}')
```

Sample run:

```
What are your answers for Q1 to Q10? (leave a space between each answer) a b d c
Q1 a
Q2 b
Q3 d
Q4 c
```

Using `split` without arguments makes it split on any kind of whitespace. The second parameter to `enumerate` is the starting value.

---

If you want to accept no more than 10 answers, you could slice the list of answers:

```
answers = answers_string.split()[:10]
```

Comment: is there a way to make the enumerate stop at Q10?

Comment: thanks for your reply! however,  after using [:10] it can only display up to Q5

Comment: i found a way by using zip Thank you!